# Gnuradio linker flag

Tags: c++, gnuradio

While compiling, I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `gr::fft::window::blackman_harris(int, int)
```

I know that this linker error is due to not having the gnuradio linker flag in my g++ command. The problem is that I have been unable to find the correct one, and also tried `-lgnuradio` and `-lgr-fft` (which don't exist).

I tried searching google, but I only find CMake related threads about gnuradio, while I'm using makefile. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can help you more, this way I just more-less guess.
The particular library name from gnuradio package starts with `libgnuradio-[lib].so`, eg. in your case libgnuradio-fft.so, so `-lgnuradio-fft`.

For finding rest of the `gnuradio` libraries in case more linking problems occur:

- use [pkg-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416956/what-is-the-significance-of-pkg-config-in-gcc), gnuradio exposes proper configuration
- find `gnuradio` libs in your system paths, depending on your system, eg. /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib, /usr/lib64, or similar. This way you know its names.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue, even with using `-lgnuradio-fft`. Turns out that I only had the versioned libraries installed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` (libgnuradio-fft.so.3.8.2 for example), so they weren't found when linking.

By using `apt-file search libgnuradio-fft.so`, I realized that I just needed to `apt install gnuradio-dev` instead of the gnuradio package.