# Opencv in UBUNTU LTS error on basic c++ program

Tags: c++, opencv, g++, static-libraries, static-linking

I installed opencv on UBUNTU 18.04 for C++. I used cmake on github source code and build in opencv/release.
But writing even a hello world program containing 
''' #include '''
is causing error on compiling with g++.
The error report is:

[image]

```
`
In file included from /usr/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp:51,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/opencv2/videoio.hpp:928:83: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct cv::DefaultDeleter<CvCapture>’
 template<> CV_EXPORTS void DefaultDeleter<CvCapture>::operator ()(CvCapture* obj) const;
                                                                                   ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:81,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:58,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /usr/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp:46,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:32:29: note: declaration of ‘struct cv::DefaultDeleter<CvCapture>’
 template<typename Y> struct DefaultDeleter;
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp:51,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/opencv2/videoio.hpp:929:91: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct cv::DefaultDeleter<CvVideoWriter>’
 template<> CV_EXPORTS void DefaultDeleter<CvVideoWriter>::operator ()(CvVideoWriter* obj) const;
                                                                                           ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:81,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:58,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /usr/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp:46,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:32:29: note: declaration of ‘struct cv::DefaultDeleter<CvVideoWriter>’
 template<typename Y> struct DefaultDeleter;
`
```

Edit: same output on

```
g++ main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o out
```

My code **main.cpp** is:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

  cv::Mat image;
  image = cv::imread("sample.jpeg" , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

  if(! image.data ) {
      std::cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
      return -1;
    }

  cv::namedWindow( "Display window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  cv::imshow( "Display window", image );

  cv::waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

> The bash output of

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

is :

```
-I/usr/include/opencv -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_video -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_viz -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_text -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```

[bash output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wneNg.png)

**System configuration:**

opencv : 3.2.0

compiler: g++

os : ubuntu

Comment: Since this is an OpenCV issue, please use the appropriate tag instead of `machine-learning` (edited).

Comment: @desertnaut ok. thanks

Comment: OpenCV version?

Comment: 3.2.0: opencv version. Though I tried with latest source code from github but same error.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to link `OpneCV` with your program.

Try the following: 
`g++ main.cpp pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv -o out`

`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` will add `include_dirs` and `link_directories`.

More explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20417398/4980722) .

Comment: I used:                `g++ main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o out` , **notice the ` please** and the same error, exactly same so I am not reproducing the error. But thanks for reply.

Comment: Try `g++ \`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv\` main.cpp -o out`.

Comment: brother, exact same error. What is DefaultDeleter error? As in both lines it is the only error!

Comment: I have included main.cpp in question

Comment: Did you `make install` your opencv?

Comment: Also please share bash output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

Comment: yes I first did cmake, then make install and then ldconfig.